# Sync ubuntu settings between systems with shell script?

Tags: command-line, scripts, sync

I am writing [a simple shell script](https://github.com/ChillarAnand/01/blob/master/ubuntu/bin/start.sh) to automatically sync packages & their configuration between several systems. However, I couldn't find a way to sync system settings.

For example:

```
System settings -> Appearance -> Behaviour -> enable auto hide launcher

System settings -> Mouse -> Enable natural scrolling
```

How can I find where those settings are stored and how to change them programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

They are in the folder `~/.config` of the user who sets them. They are not system-wide settings, but user-wide.

Comment: There are all the settings. Exactly which one do you want to save? You gave just an example. If you make a detailed list, we can be more helpful.

Comment: Are those all? Or is there others?

Comment: If you tell me how to access & modify them, i can figure out remaining settings.